# Return value that depends on results from promises in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I want a function that returns a message depending on the response from promises but I can't get the resolved value.

```
function create() {
  var check = promise1();
  var increment = promise2( check );
  var create = promise3( increment );

  if ( create === 1 ) {
    return {
      message: `Item with id ${increment} created`,
      value: 'OK'
    }
  } else {
    return {
      message: `Item not created`,
      value: 'FAIL'
    }
  }
}

var res = create()
  // I want it to return the json if the item was created
  // but instead they return promises and I have to use then
  // I can't think of another way

console.log( res );
```

Would it help if I show you how the code from the promises look like?

The code is a lot more complex but I tried to simplify to the extreme.

//SOLVED
EDIT:

```
function create( responsecb ) {
  var check = promise1();
  var increment = promise2( check );
  var create = promise3( increment );

  if ( create === 1 ) {
    responsecb( {
      message: `Item with id ${increment} created`,
      value: 'OK'
    } )
  } else {
    responsecb( {
      message: `Item not created`,
      value: 'FAIL'
    } )
  }
}

create.then(console.log)
```

I just have to create a callback which does something with the response.

Comment: Did you mean `promise3( increment );`?

Comment: Yes just edited, thank you.

Comment: If you use promises inside `create()`, that makes it an asynchronous function. Every caller of `create()` then needs to treat it as an asynchronous function and use callbacks/promises to get its result. You can't synchronise an asynchronous function.

Comment: I think I got it, thank you for the already answered post, I will come back with a new version in no time as an answer.